# Different types of boxes/frames around the title of my pdf

Tags: graphics, boxes, titles

Can someone tell me how to create boxes around the title of my PDF? I'm thinking about something like this:

[image]

where I can write stuff around the title (which is "test test...").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the font formatting options contains some basic mistakes but here is an attempt to make simple title page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{30mm}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center,draw,thick,minimum width=\textwidth,inner sep=6mm] (titlebox)%
{\textsc{\large Mathematical Minutae}\\[\baselineskip]\textbf{\huge Test Test Test Test}};
\node[fill=white] (W) at (titlebox.north) {\bfseries \Huge W};
\node (feat) at ([yshift=9mm]titlebox.north) {\textsc{\Large Feature}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which gives: 
[image]

I didn't understand quite the last sentence in which you wrote *around the title*, but I hope I got it right.

By the way, I would like to mention whenever I can that I am looking forward to the highly anticipated work of Altermundus, [pgfvectorian package](http://altermundus.com/SandBox/project_vectorian.zip), on carrying ornaments of psvectorian goodies to TikZ/PGF, (I think it is a wonderful attempt to even consider it). So we can even put more beautiful stuff instead of plain boxes (not that it is ugly but it's always to have *moar* options).

*EDIT* A simple macro to have some more automation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\titlebox}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center,draw,thick,text width=\textwidth,inner sep=6mm] (titlebox)%
{\textsc{\large Mathematical Minutae}\\[\baselineskip]\textbf{\huge #1}};
\node[fill=white] (W) at (titlebox.north) {\bfseries \Huge W};
\node (feat) at ([yshift=9mm]titlebox.north) {\textsc{\Large Feature}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{30mm}% This introduces some space you can remove or change it.
\titlebox{My title test is a test that tests \\ my title} % An example use

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent; that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. I still have a question though: could you tell me how to place this beautiful box around the title (meaning the exact place where the text "Test test" would appear if I used \title{Test test})? I have no clue how to use tikz (I thought that there would be ready-made boxes to put around the title), so I couldn't figure out how to manipulate your code to change the coordinates to put the picture so that "Test test..." is where the title would be....

Comment: @user10324 Ah, I hope I now see what you mean. You want to provide the option and the title is printed automatically. Well, as it is, you can simply find and modify the `Test Test Test` part in the code without actually requiring to use the `\title{}` command and carry on with what you would like to have for the rest of the document. I will try to update this when I come up with a simpler macro. Can you tell me once again for the sake of confirmation exactly which part is going to be positioned and what needs to be changed?

Comment: The place in the box, where "Test test..." is written, is where the title should be. To confirm: What I wanted was a hypothetical command '\titlebox{Test test}', that should create a box like above around the title "Test test" (meaning  "Test test" is placed where /title{Test test} would place it; or differently: After using '\titlebox{Test test}', using  the command /title{Test test} shouldn't visually change anything).

Comment: I played around with your code an could change the "Test test..." myself, just by editing the appropriate line of code. What I couldn't change though is the location of the whole box in the page: It is centered, but I higher up on the page, so that, like in my previous comment described, the "Test test" string from the box should be where  \Title{Test test} would place it. If I only could move that box higher, my problem would be solved. Doing a macro would of course be even nicer, but maybe overkill, I think.

Comment: @user10324 See my edit. I think the comments are more informative now.