# How to adjust the width of a frame to a given text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, width

I'm currently trying to get a frame around some text or pictures with an header as the "W" in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45643/31058). My code is actually the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\titlebox}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center,draw,thick,text width=\textwidth,inner sep=6mm] (titlebox) {#2};
\node[fill=white] (Title) at (titlebox.north) {\bfseries \large #1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\titlebox{Title}{Text in the frame.}

\end{document}
```

which yields this:

[image: Frame and text]

My question is how to make sure that the width of the frame will automatically fit the width of the inner text or elements (pictures)?

Comment: Remove the `text width` key of the titlebox. Of course, if parameter `#2` contains a lot of text, it will be typeset in a single long line. You can avoid that passing a `\parbox` of the required width as argument to your `\titlebox`.

Comment: @JLDiaz an answer? :)

Comment: You might also consider to use [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) for this: I remember having seen a couple of similar examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `text width` key of the titlebox (`align=center` is not required either in this case).

Of course, if parameter `#2` contains a lot of text, it will be typeset in a single long line. You can avoid that passing a `\parbox` of the required width as argument to your `\titlebox`, as the following example shows.

```
\newcommand{\titlebox}[2]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,thick,inner sep=6mm] (titlebox) {#2};
\node[fill=white] (Title) at (titlebox.north) {\bfseries \large #1};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\titlebox{Title}{Text in the frame.}

\titlebox{Another example}{\parbox{4cm}{
This is a longer text which will be typeset in a paragraph with a width of 4cm.
}}
```

[image: Result]